# openlayers 3 , clustering polygons or linestings

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

i've been searching for a way to cluster polygons using openlayers 3 but no luck. i've read that clustering only works with points so i'm thinking about editing the ol.source.cluster .
so had anyone done it, or got any other solutions?

Kind regards

Comment: I would also be interested in a dynamic way to do this on the client. Currently I do the clustering on the server by creating a bounding polygon of the smaller ones and then add these bounding polygons as an additional layer to the map. Then depending on the resolution either the detailed layer or the bounding layer is displayed

Answer (score 1):

As of openlayers 3.15.0, it is possible to cluster all geometry types using an optional function, `geometryFunction`. From http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.0/apidoc/ol.source.Cluster.html:

> Function that takes an ol.Feature as argument and returns an ol.geom.Point as
>   cluster calculation point for the feature. When a feature should not
>   be considered for clustering, the function should return null.
>   See ol.geom.Polygon#getInteriorPoint for a way to get a cluster
>   calculation point for polygons.