# Openlayers 3 Cluster by polygons

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geojson

I wonder clustering point but delimit by polygons.

I already know how to cluster but I don't know how do not mix points where not in the same polygones. My polygons are stocked in a GeoJson

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments yet, so I was wondering what you meant by 'delimit by polygons'?

Do you mean you have a source which has both points and polygons and you also want to cluster the polygons? Or do you not want to cluster polygons and only cluster the points?

Openlayers 3.15 clusterSource has an option called geometryFunction which allows you to cluster any geometry shape. Look at my answer at 
[openlayers 3 , clustering polygons or linestings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29032383/openlayers-3-clustering-polygons-or-linestings/36400313#36400313)

Comment: I have polygon of countries in my GeoJson and I have coordinates of points. Now I want to group the items by country. If I zoom out, points for each country includes but do not mix between countries

Comment: But for now I will create a cluster by countries, I will work-do it later ;)